# Challenge using python insert method

Tags: python, list, class, methods, insert

i am trying my hands on some python list practice question. i tried to insert a new name mike at index "-1" but upon printing output to the screen i noticed it defaulted to another position (index (-2))in the dinner list.

```
dinner = ['yemi', 'bimpe', 'kola', 'kunle', 'bola', 'shola', 'ola']

invite = f"{dinner[0].title()}, would you be available to attend our dinner party?"
print(invite)

invite = f"{dinner[-1].title()}, would you be available to attend our dinner party?"
print(invite)

invite = f"{dinner[-3].title()}, would you be available to attend our dinner party?"
print(invite)

invite = f"{dinner[3].title()}, would you be available to attend our dinner party?"
print(invite)

invite = f"{dinner[1].title()}, would you be available to attend our dinner party?"
print(invite)

not_coming = f"{dinner[0].title()} said she can't make the dinner party tonight and has to be swapped with {dinner[1].title()}"
print(not_coming)

not_coming = f"{dinner[-1].title()} said she can't make the dinner party tonight and has to be swapped with {dinner[-2].title()}"
print(not_coming)

dinner.insert(0, "kingsley")
print(dinner)

dinner.insert(-1, "mike")
print(dinner)
```

why is this so?

the list name is "dinner"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) states

> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert

So if you use the index `-1`, it'll insert just before the last one

---

To insert last use either one of these

```
dinner.insert(len(dinner), "mike")
dinner.append("mike")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I got clarity now.

Comment: @yuppiesam you can think about accepting the answer so ;)